# having trouble setting up simple rectangular collisions in chipmunk

Tags: ruby, collision-detection, chipmunk, libgosu

Recently I've been trying to create something I've always wanted, but never had the skill and time to do - a computer game. To be more precise, a homage / clone of one of many of my favourite games. To start with something simple I've decided to create a classic 2D platform based on the Castlevania series.

Being a Ruby programmer I've decided to use [Gosu](http://www.libgosu.org/%20Gosu). Then I decided I don't want to reinvent the wheel so I'm going to use [Chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/).

After a few days, I've ended up having inexplicable collision detection problems. I've added boundary-box drawing functions just to see what the hell is going on.

[image]

As you can see, Belmont collides with blocks of walls he's not remotely close to touching. Since the demo game included with gosu gem works fine, there must be something wrong I'm doing, I probably don't really udnerstand how a polygon `Shape` is defined and added to the space. I'm pretty sure it's not really where I draw it.

There's a public repo with the game, so you can see how walls (`Brush < Entity`) and player (`Player < Entity`) are defined and that they indeed have a simple, rectangular polygon shape. Walls are not added to the space (they are *rogue*), only the player is. I've tried debugging the game and see where the `body` position is, but all looked fine.

https://github.com/ellmo/castellvania

Player falls down slowly, but you can control him with up / left / right arrows. Tilde button (`~`) shows the boudning boxes and the collision boxes are supposed to be always visible.

I need some help trying to understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I probably don't really udnerstand how a polygon Shape is defined and added to the space. I'm pretty sure it's not really where I draw it.

That's it. Shape coordinates are added to the body position, not substracted from it.
In your `Entity.boundaries` replace the line

```
verts << CP::Vec2.new(@shape.body.p.x - @shape[vert].x, @shape.body.p.y - @shape[vert].y)
```

with

```
verts << CP::Vec2.new(@shape.body.p.x + @shape[vert].x, @shape.body.p.y + @shape[vert].y)
```

and you will get correct picture. (drawing will be still broken, but bounding boxes will be correct.